# How to run several times a model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I want to train several times a file `ConvNet.py` in order to produce some statistics about its training like precision, confussion matrices, etc. So, I tried (in google colab) to do something like

```
for k in range(10:
    %run ConvNet.py
```

The first training goes well, but when in begin the second, arise a problem. It says that "`weights` variable already defined, disallowed" (`weights` is the fist variable that I define in ConvNet.py) and the script stops.

I tried clearing variables with os kill, but there is still problems. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better if you do the iterated training in Python directly.

You haven't shared much about your setup, but you can do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="sigmoid"))

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


for i in range(10):
    model = build_model()

    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    model.save_weights(f"./weights-{i}.hdf5")
```

And when you want to do the analysis:

```
for i in range(10):
    model = build_model()

    model.load_weights(f"./weights-{i}.hdf5")

    do_analysis(model)
```